# Plot 3D for ODE

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

So I am trying to `Plot3D` this first-order ODE:

$$ y'(x) = y$$

with the 3d coordinates (x,y,y'). I have read the documentation in Mathematica about 3DPlot and tried to "transfer" what I learned from there but it did not work. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you already seen `ParametricPlot3D[]`?

Comment: I just read it now, and I tried several things but it still has not worked out for me yet even though I feel like I have an idea after reading it.

Comment: `Clear["Global\`*"]; 

sol[y0_] = DSolve[{y'[x] == y[x], y[0] == y0}, y, x][[1]]; 

ParametricPlot3D[{x, y[x], y'[x]} /. sol[1], {x, -3, 2}]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [`NDSolveValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue.html) and [`ParametricPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html):

```
ClearAll[ndsv]
ndsv[iv_?NumericQ] := NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == y[x], y[0] == iv}, {# &, y, y'}, {x, 0, 10}]

ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[Table[Through@ndsv[iv]@t, {iv, 0, 3, .5}]], {t, 0, 10}, 
 BoxRatios -> 1, PlotLegends -> LineLegend[Range[0, 3, .5], LegendLabel -> "y[0]"]]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot3D[Through@ndsv[u]@t, {t, 0, 10}, {u, 0, 3}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#5 &}, 
 Mesh -> {MapIndexed[{#, Directive[Thick, ColorData[97][#2[[1]]]]} &, Range[0, 3, .5]]},  
 BoxRatios -> 1, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5, Blue], 
 Method -> "BoundaryOffset" -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral",
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[97, Range[0, 3, .5], LegendLabel -> "y[0]"]]
```

[image]

Comment: Can we somehow "connect" all the line together so that the plot becomes like a smooth and continuous surface?

Comment: @TuanDucVu, please see the update.

Comment: It seems like I have to learn quite a few more things in order to fully understand your code up there -- any suggestion would be appreciated --, but anyhow this is what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @TuanDucVu, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept. And welcome mma.se.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
sol[y0_] = DSolve[{y'[x] == y[x], y[0] == y0}, y, x][[1]];

Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[
  {x, y[x], y'[x]} /. sol[y0],
  {x, -3, 2}, {y0, 0, 5},
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.8],
  Mesh -> None],
 ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate@
   Table[{x, y[x], y'[x]} /. sol[y0], {y0, 5, 0, -1}],
  {x, -3, 2},
  PlotLegends -> LineLegend[Automatic, Range[5, 0, -1],
    LegendLabel -> y[0]]],
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, y[x], y'[x]}),
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]